# i want to move only temp files from those top 60 file to some folder

Tags: shell

```
du -mx --exclude='.snapshot' | sort -n -r|head -n 60
```

after the execution of this command I am getting list of 60 files out of 1000   files which are present in that folder, where I want to move only temp files from   those top 60 file to some folder. I tried with below command but its not working.

```
du -mx --exclude='.snapshot' | sort -n -r|head -n 60 | cp *temp /mnt/TEST/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
du -mx --exclude='.snapshot' | sort -n -r | head -n 60 | grep temp | xargs cp {} /mnt/TEST/
```

I'm not what your files names look like, so I put in a `grep` on `temp`.  You should modify that as needed.
Once it works, you will need to replace `cp` with `mv`.

Comment: You should add -i to the xargs to use {}